# angular ui-select and form validation $touched not working together

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have this validation-message-tag

```
<div class="validation-message-tag" ng-show="ctrl.data && ctrl.$touched">
  <p ng-repeat="message in success track by $index" class="validation-success">{{message}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="message in info track by $index" class="validation-info">{{message}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="message in warning track by $index" class="validation-warning">{{message}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="message in error track by $index" class="validation-error">{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

And input field using ui-select

```
      <lable for="tags">Tags</lable>
      <div id="tags">
        <tag-picker-tag ng-model="entity.meta.tags" editable="true" name="tags" check-valid-user-meta-tags></tag-picker-tag>
        <validation-message-tag ctrl="form.tags"></validation-message-tag>
      </div>
```

tag-picker-tag:

```
<div class="tag-picker-tag">
  tags
  <ui-select ng-model="$parent.tags" ng-disabled="! editable" multiple tagging tagging-tokens="SPACE|," tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" title="Select tags" sortable="true" theme="bootstrap" >
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter Tags...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in suggestedTags | filter:$select.search">
      {{tag}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{tags}}</p>
</div>
```

The validator does fail successfully for invalid input with a correct validation message. But the validation message is not shown because $touched always false. I have tried the same for other input like text area, and only ui-select does not work.

So is there a way to support ui-select with angular $touched field? or is there other boolean flag I can use from ui-select?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `<ui-select>`, but regular `<input>` updates *$touched*, after you leave that field. Use *$dirty*, which will change into true, after you modify value.